# WordPress error: cannot redeclare function with Thesis theme

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress version 3.8.1
Thesis Theme version 1.8
Linux Centos Server 6.1
Plugin: PHP Execution Version 1

I have a page where some code will execute, by running a script. I am including the script using the PHP Execution Plugin, as follows:

```
<?php
    require '/home/mine/public_html/events/myscript.php';
?>
```

When I review the page, here's what I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_list_of_attendees() (previously declared in /home/mine/public_html/events/myscript.php:46) in /home/mine/public_html/events/myscript.php on line 64
```

Line 64 is the PHP script's last line, and I am not re-declaring the function anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: hommy try with require_once since wordpress is a damn loop dog. so make sure it only include the file once

Comment: OK, so this stopped the error, but now my script is not executing. I'll look into that

Comment: sorry for the message, i just couldn't resist for your username mate lol